# Python read list from file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to sort a list from a file, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacbookPro/Documents/Faculta/alg sortare pyth/bubble.py", line 13, in <module>
    f = file.open('lista.txt', 'r')
AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'open'
```

This is my code:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import resource
start = timer()
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp


f = file.open('lista.txt', 'r')
long_string = f.readline()
my_list = long_string.split(',')
bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist), resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

Answer (score 2):

**To open a file use:**

```
f = open('lista.txt', 'r')
```

**Use a context manager instead:**

```
with open('lista.txt', 'r') as f:
    long_string = f.readline()
    my_list = long_string.split(',')
    ....
```

The context manager approach will automatically close the file.  This especially true when writing a file, but is best practice here also.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
f = file.open('lista.txt', 'r')
```

with this one:

```
f= open('lista.txt', 'r')
```